# Swarm rescheduling after adding new node

Tags: docker, swarm

With the new version of Rancher is it possible to tell docker SWARM (1.12+) to redistribute containers when I add a new node in my infrastructure?

Suppose I have 4 nodes with 5 containers on each, if I add a 5th node, I'd like to redistribute my containers to have 4 of them on each node.

When a node crashes or it shuts down (scaling down my cluster), the re-scheduling triggers well, but when I scale up by adding 1 or more nodes, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible to do this. What you can do, is update a service with `docker service update` (i.e.: by adding an environment variable)

A new feature coming in docker 1.13 will be a force update of services, that will update the service and force the redistribution of nodes, so something like `docker service update --force $(docker service ls -q)` might be possible (haven't tried this yet, so can't confirm yet).

You can find more info about this feature in this [blogpost](https://blog.nimbleci.com/2016/11/17/whats-coming-in-docker-1-13/#service-update---force)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. But rather than because of adding a new node, I had a node failure on the underling shared storage between nodes (was using shared NFS storage for sharing mount points of read only configs).

The docker service update --force $(docker service ls -q) as of version Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be does not work.

scale-up.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the amount by which you want to scale your services (NUMBER), followed by ENTER: "
read SCALENUM

for OUTPUT in $(docker service ls | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '1!p')
do
    echo "Scaling up "$OUTPUT" to "$SCALENUM
    docker service scale $OUTPUT=$SCALENUM
done
```

scale-down.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for OUTPUT in $(docker service ls | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '1!p')
do
    echo "Scaling down "$OUTPUT" to 0"
    docker service scale $OUTPUT=0
done
```

Note that the second script SCALES DOWN the service, making it unavailable. You can also use the following command as a starting point for other scripting you may need, as this prints out the service name independently of the other columns in a typical docker service ls command:

```
$(docker service ls | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n '1!p')
```

I hope this helps!